# Update query for data coming from 2 different tables in a single query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `X_Data` where some data is saved based on `Itemcodes`. I have another table `Item_Master` where the item details are stored. In both tables there is a column called `leadtime`. But in table `X_Data`, it gets updated by some stored procedure calculations.

For certain condition, I need this data to be refreshed with the one I have in `Item_Master` table. I don't want to include any loop or stored procedure for this.

Is it possible to update the data in `X_Data` table for all items using a single query?

Comment: Please mention your code here also

Comment: A standard UPDATE statement will update all records that match the condition.